# Create an issue WITH labels via GitHub API,

Tags: github-api

I am trying to add an issue to a GitHub repository via the GitHub API. I use OAuth with a scope of user,repo,gist. The issue gets created just fine, but the labels are silently dropped.

I read on the GitHub website:

> "Only users with push access can set labels for new issues. Labels are
>   silently dropped otherwise."

So my question is this: What is push access? Do I need to add something to my scope to allow a user to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need to be authenticated as a user that is allowed to push (as in `git push`) to the repository. That means, either the repository owner or a collaborator ("Settings" >> "Collaborators").

Comment: So in other words, push access is not something one can get via the GitHub API? You can only be granted push access by one of the collaborators

Comment: Seems so. I mean, there is [this API call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-collaborator) but if you were able to execute it you should probably already be able to add labels to issues.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across this while looking for a simple **URL-way** to add labels to issues.

Turns out there is something: it's `labels=`!

So on a new issue where it's the first param that'd be:

```
https://github.com/github/issue-labeler/issues/new?labels=bug,enhancement
```

Otherwise `&labels=...`

This also works if you **don't** have any **push access**!

Of course nonexistent labels are also silently dropped and this does not yet submit the issue. I'm sorry if it does not apply.